# How to use Query and Importrange using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need updated info from master sheets using query and importrange using apps script.
This is master sheet. From which I need to access info:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tpv0iGwpnLUw6F5FoLn2jE4FBuF_igjriLA5uyNjczw/edit#gid=0

And this is sheet in which I need to show data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ENZdtWI2f_wYzKbqUNziw6bVcTCpP6T4vkPbs-lPgC0/edit#gid=0

Currently I am using to fetch date. But I need to use Apps Script. `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tpv0iGwpnLUw6F5FoLn2jE4FBuF_igjriLA5uyNjczw/edit#gid=0","Task!A:J"),"SELECT* WHERE Col7 = 'JOHN'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to import data from a source spreadsheet to another spreadsheet when column `G` has a certain value.

In that case, you can use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) for this:

```
const SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID = "1qkCxwyspeRrVcQRFqiHmIXRUjbrz9zgp09pYR0Y6_-M";
const TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID = "1zp34NKnqRqdNvDzJx70T1spb0GbUQwnpUmJgkF81Pr4";
const SOURCE_SHEET_NAME = "Task";
const TARGET_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
const NAME_COL_INDEX = 7;
const NAME = "JOHN";

function copyData() {
  const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SOURCE_SHEET_NAME);
  const sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:J" + sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const targetValues = sourceValues.filter((row,i) => i === 0 || row[NAME_COL_INDEX-1] === NAME);
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(TARGET_SHEET_NAME);
  targetSheet.clearContents();
  targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetValues.length,targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues);
}

function installOnEditTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyData")
           .forSpreadsheet(ss)
           .onEdit()
           .create();
}
```

#### Note:

If you want this to update automatically whenever users edit the source spreadsheet, consider [installing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite). To do that in the example above, execute `installOnEditTrigger` once.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate this code:  `filter((row,i) => i === 0 || row[NAME_COL_INDEX-1] === NAME);`
And one thing more. How can I give access using app script?

Comment: @user8702720 `filter((row,i) => i === 0 || row[NAME_COL_INDEX-1] === NAME);` means we want to filter out all data that is not the header row (`i === 0`) or whose `G` column value is `JOHN`.

Comment: Thank you. If I update source Sheet, target Sheet is not updating automatically. How can I do that? @Iamblichus

Comment: @user8702720 In that case, install an onEdit trigger. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I have updated the script. But It still does not update the target sheet automatically when I edit the source sheet. Can you please look into the script in the target sheet?
I have to run the script again to see updated data in the target sheet. @lamblichus

Comment: @user8702720 I tested this before posting it, the script is working. Now, I can think of two reasons for this not working for you: (1) you didn't install the trigger (execute installOnEditTrigger once), (2) the source spreadsheet is getting updated automatically, and not manually by a user (the onEdit trigger only listens to manual updates).